# rails skip an after_action in a controller/method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-4.2

In my controller I have an after_action block.  I want to stop the after_action from running when the method in question fails.

Rails 4.2, ruby 2.2

Does anyone know how to do this in rails?

```
class MyController  < ApplicationController

  after_action only: :show do
    # do so and so
  end

  def show
    begin
      # something really bad happens here... My Nose!

    rescue => e 

      # how do I stop after_action from running?

      flash[:error] = 'Oh noes... Someone make a log report'
      redirect_to '/'
      return
    end

    # yarda yarda yarda

  end
end
```

Comment: Why not create a function and call it with conditionals within the show(action) method.

Comment: I removed it, but I use action caching on :show.

Comment: Going through the documentation there is no way you could have conditional callbacks for an action. I guess you have to put some logic in your callback's block. Else wait for a better opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it like this.  Set an instance variable if the the show action errors and check that variable in the after action:

```
class MyController  < ApplicationController

  after_action only: :show do
    unless @skip_after_action
      # after action code here
    end
  end

  def show
    begin
      # something really bad happens here...
    rescue => e 
      @skip_after_action = true
      flash[:error] = 'Oh noes... Someone make a log report'
      redirect_to '/'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Seams to be the only option in town. :(

Answer (score 0):

From a comment on these docs https://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/after_action

> You can pass an proc for o callback with the conditions
>
> ```rb
> after_action :initial_value, only: [:index, :show], unless: -> { @foo.nil? }
>
> after_action :initial_value, only: [:index, :show], if: -> { @foo }
> ```

there's also https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_after_action